# MSOLEDBSQL connect string using MultiSubnetFailover=Yes generates "Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification"

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string

When using **MSOLEDBSQL** in the 18.x series (specifically 18.5.0 - 18.6.5, others not tested yet) with a **SQL Server availability group** and specifying **MultiSubnetFailover=Yes** combined with **.NET OleDbConnection** usage, the connection fails with

"Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification"

An example connection string
*Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MultiSubnetFailover=Yes;Connect Timeout=30;Server=tcp:AvailabilityGroupListenerDnsName,port;Database=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;*

On ConnectionStrings.com the MultiSubnetFailover is specified as "Yes".

https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/availability-group-and-failover-cluster/

On Microsoft's write up the MultiSubnetFailover can be "True" or "Yes" depending on how initialize is called.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

When using .NET OleDbConnection object it seems the only valid value of MultiSubnetFailover is "True".  "Yes" generates the error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-data-oledb-oledbconnection-connectionstring

I don't understand why "Yes" is triggering the error.  Is it related to how the MSOLEDBSQL and .NET OleDbConnection interact with one another?

Comment: why are you putting quotes around "yes"?

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT to make it clear to the reader the exact content I'm trying to communicate. i.e. no trailing spaces or other chars before or after other words in the sentence.  The value used in the connection string is Yes without quotes.  I'll add an example connection string.

Comment: @DaveWilliamson, only `true` is allowed because .NET apparently uses [GetDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#using-idatainitializegetdatasource) for the ADO.NET implementation. Personally, I suggest one use the official vendor doc rather than third party (connectionstrings.com).

Comment: I guess my question would be: why use MSOLEDBSQL instead of (the now legacy) `System.Data.SqlClient` for .NET 4.x Framework applications and services or the modern `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` for all new projects?

Comment: If you put quotes in the actual string value="yes" I don't expect it to work.  value=yes is what the spec says.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning this is addressing an older oledb based product that needs to work with a sql availability group. Eventually the code will be changed to the more current sqlclient.